# Js, impossible to remove a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

in my project i use js,dom and ajax for create pages.
I need to know if an element already exist and if so, remove it.

i try this

```
var elementL =  document.getElementById('divLogin');
if (typeof(elementL) != 'undefined' && elementL != null)
{
    document.body.removeChild(divLogin);
}
```

but console respond

> Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

then i write:

```
var elementL =  document.getElementById('divLogin');
if (typeof(elementL) != 'undefined' && elementL != null)
{
    divLogin.parentNode.removeChild(divLogin);
}
```

and console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

How can i delete this element??

Thanks in advance

Comment: What a strange question title for a simple typo. “Not able to debug my code” would suite best…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `divLogin.parentNode.removeChild(divLogin);` but your variable is called `elementL`. Change your code to use your variable and it will work:

```
elementL.parentNode.removeChild(elementL);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it depends mainly on browser you use. If you use Chrome then your code should work, because every element with defined ID has its own js object representation in this browser.